# GNOME problem reporting keeps crashing

Tags: fedora, gnome, crash, abrt

I am experiencing issues with the GNOME problem reporting software (`gnome-abrt`). I open it up because I want to report the errors I get (I get a lot of crashes in software **and** system crashes) but `libreport` itself crashes and doesn't let me report the issues.

At first I thought it was the custom theme I installed that was causing this:

```
~$ gnome-abrt

(gnome-abrt:12043): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:39.302: Theme parsing error: main-dark.css:2470:0: Expected a valid selector

(org.freedesktop.GnomeAbrt:12068): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:42.849: Theme parsing error: main-dark.css:2470:0: Expected a valid selector
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

But switching back to the default theme causes the same:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the [Gnome Professional theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1334194/)? I'm using the same one, and I'm getting the same error, on the same line in main-dark.css. I'm switching back to Adwaita theme for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug in libreport](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1965633). It's already [fixed upstream](https://github.com/abrt/libreport/pull/726) so we can expect a new libreport build for Fedora fixing this issue soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have just disabled and deleted the main-dark theme, called again the command that had returned error, and it executed smoothly. It seems that the Gnome Professional Theme was indeed the cause of the issue! Thanks to the comment by [heyheyhey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/476179/heyheyhey) for putting me on the right path!